# How to have conditional database seeding in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Can I create seed groups? For instance I have seeds that I only want executed some of the time. How can I add a flag when executing `php artisan migrate --seed --group1`

What are my options for such feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what you could do is create multiple `Seeder` extended classes, and having each one of them running `$this->call()` on a specific group of tables and then specify which one you want using the `--class` flag. Something like this:

```
class GroupOneDatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run() {
        Eloquent::unguard();

        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');
        $this->call('RoleTableSeeder');
    }

}
```

And then call it this way:

```
php artisan db:seed --class="GroupOneDatabaseSeeder"
```

Well, that or you could extend the `SeedCommand` to add this functionality via methods instead of classes.